# LDAP over SSL on windows service

Tags: c++, ssl, ldap

I have an application that connects to an LDAP server using SSL. The problem I'm having is that when I run it as a console application it connects successfully, but when I run the application as a windows service, it fails.

There is some information that could help:

- ldap_sslinit ALLWAYS returns success

1 ldap_connect = 0 (Success) with all the LDAP ports running as APPLICATION under user ADMINISTRATOR
  tested ports 389,3268 without ssl    and  636,3269 with SSL
2 ldap_connect = 0 (Success) running as service with port 389  or 3268
3 ldap_connect = 81 (Not connected) running AS SERVICE with ports 636 or 3269
   We tested the service running under user administrator 
   and also tested under other special user agent with all the permisions

- We enabled some Log on as service permissions, and others without success.
- We also added the certificates to local machine , and to the service user

---

Example of the test

```
pLdapConnection = ldap_sslinit((PWCHAR)ldap_host.c_str(), ldap_port,1); // Secure LDAP 
// allways return success
ldap_set_option(pLdapConnection, LDAP_OPT_SSL, LDAP_OPT_ON); // set SSL option
ldap_set_option(pLdapConnection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, LDAP_OPT_OFF); // required  
result = ldap_connect(pLdapConnection, &timeout);
```

result = LDAP_SERVER_DOWN (0x51)

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

What account is the service running under?  Is it a specific domain user that has access to the LDAP server?  You might want to [set the SPNs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755442(WS.10).aspx) on the LDAP server as well; I've had double-hop token problems before with authentication.

Comment: Here is more info...

Run Service as: local user, administrator, ezbio-agent user.

Changes in Group Policy Properties: add Logon as Service permissions to administrator, guest, etc....
 
dsHeuristics=0000002
 
DN Security Permissions: Add Guest, Add Anonymous Logon, Add Network Service,  Add Local Service

ezbio-agent 
   special user created to run the agent with all the permissions for everything

Comment: So, you run it from the console you can connect over SSL or unencrypted (which I assume you are doing using 1 or 0 in the last parameter of ldap_sslinit), but running as a service as the same user you can only connect unencrypted?  If it was an untrusted CA, it shouldn't matter how it's run.  I can't think of a reason why it should matter.